# is $\ell_{2}$ space Banach algebra?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $\ell_{2}$ space Banach algebra ? By $\ell_{2}$, we mean the space of all sequences of complex
numbers $( x_{n})$ for which $\sum|x_{k}|^{2}<\infty$.

Comment: Yes, it is a Banach algebra.

Comment: By which product?

Answer (score -1):

```
The space l₂ is closed under multiplication. For let x, y be in this space. Then there is N such that ∣x_{i}∣,∣y_{i}∣<1,i≥N. Then ∑(x_{i}y_{i})²=∑_{i≥N}(x_{i}y_{i})²+∑_{i<N}(x_{i}y_{i})²
<∑_{i<N}(x_{i}y_{i})²+∑_{i≥N}∣x_{i}y_{i}∣. For positive a,b we have a^{1/2}b^{1/2}≤(a+b)/2. Thus 
((∣x_{i}y_{i}∣)/(∥x∥∥y∥))≤((∣x_{i}∣²/∥x∥²+∣y_{i}∣²/∥y∥²)/2). A little work shows that ∑_{i<N}(x_{i}y_{i})²+∑_{i≥N}∣x_{i}y_{i}∣<∞. Minkowwski's inequality holds. Thus the space is an algebra. But it does not contain 1 and so it is not a Banach algebra.
```

Comment: By this  multiplication $(a_{n})(b_{n})=(a_{n}b_{n})}$?

Comment: Why it is not  Banach algebra ?